# VLOOKUP partial names and with typing or spelling errors

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

```
Column A - full names 
Column B - first names
Column C - surnames
```

Goal: find people in both lists (list 2 has its names split into 2 columns*)

Problem: can't search for a surname from a full name, and names are misspelled or typed wrongly, example

```
Column A: Jack Doyle
Column B: Jack
Column C: Doyles
```

I've got something like the following for looking up the first name (even if this name was Jackson), but I can't figure out the wildcard/LEFT/RIGHT for the surname, especially considering the known errors.

```
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(B138,4)&"*",A$1:A$999,1,FALSE)
```

I've tried wildcards before and after, a tilde, just not sure where to go...

*Speaking of this, is there an easy way to append a bunch of surnames to first names in back-to-back columns? A=Jack,B=Doyle,C=Jack Doyle (must have the space obv)?

Comment: Try using `MATCH` instead which supports wildcards. Otherwise a full [Hamming Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) calculation to *guess* if it's a typo or actually a different name will take a bit of effort if you have more "typos" than just a random plural.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> with typing or spelling errors

this can't be really done. but you can force auto-suggestions if you put all names from all 3 columns into one column and then apply Data validation with hidden dropdown.

[image: 0]

**B4:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SPLIT(A4:A, " ")))
```

**D4:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(B4:B&" "&C4:C)
```

**E4:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(D4:D, " "), "select Col2,Col1", 0))
```

**I3:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(H3:H5, {B4:B,C4:C;C4:C,B4:B}, 2, 0)))
```

**P3:**

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY({B4:B;C4:C}, "where Col1 is not null", 0))
```

---

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lHRgvklOxjw5JcHJRA_NfI6cRBSCnEu_Fvq0dqlEvac/copy)

Comment: Thank you, I don't have time to check right now and I don't think I was probably the clearest in my post, but I appreciate your effort - so I wanted to say thanks. =)